# detecting last entered character's index number in a textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, textfield, keypress

I'm getting the last entered character in textfield "message" by the code below:

```
$('#message').on("keypress", function(event) {
              var a= String.fromCharCode(event.which);}
```

I also want to get the index number of the last entered character but can't find any solution. I tried some combinations with indexOf and findIndex but couldn't get them to work.

Comment: `String.fromCharCode` expects a number not an event. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode

Comment: Also, the keypress event is deprecated. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event

Comment: You mean this is the string 'hello', suppose i have entered last character 'o' then it will return 4 (if we count from zero)?

Comment: @turivishal yes that's what  I mean, Niklas E it works just fine, I'm checking the link thank you btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it `target.selectionStart` method, like this:

```js
$('#message').on("keypress", function(event) {
    var a = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    console.log("Char:" + a, "Position:" + event.target.selectionStart);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="message" value=""/>
```